# diamond question marks in console when loading wav file into memory, how do I reencode to binary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wav

I'm trying to move a recording in wav format from a web address to Amazon s3 using JavaScript, AWS-SDK and http requests.

This is to pull recordings out of Twilio one at a time and back them up or process them on AWS.

I think I'm missing something in the encoding options for the request, as I keep getting wav files that are just static or don't open.

file_location is something like http://www.foo.com/bar.wav.
the file is a stereo wav file at 128kbps.

```
  // read relevant file into memory
function bufferFile(file_name, file_location) {
  console.log(file_location);

  var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: file_location,
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'audio/wav', // pretty sure these two lines are not right
     'encoding' : 'null' }     // pretty sure these two lines are not right
  };

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      file_contents = body;
      console.log(file_contents);  // spits out unreadable characters

      awsS3 (file_name, file_contents);
  }
})};
```

I expect binary from the console but I get this instead.

```
RIFF�#4 WAVEfmt      @   }    data�#4     ��     ��       B  B   !       ��          ��  ��  !   ��          ��      ��  ��      ��  ��  ����  ��!   B ��    !  !  B   B   ��  ��  ��      ��  ��         ��  ��  !  !               ��  ��  ��  ��     !   !     ��! ��C      ��     !   "   B ����     !   ��  ��        ��  �� ��  !             !   B   !   B  ��������!  "   ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��      ��          ��        ��  ����      �     ����  !   "   C  ! ���� ��  B ��  ����  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��      ��  ��    B ��       B   A   !   ��  ��          ��     !   !       ��  B     ��              ��  ��            ��    !    ����  ��                  !     ����        ����  ��      A ��B     ���� C   !   ����|�     c ��B   !       �  B   ��  {�  !   B   ��  ��  ��  B ����  Z�  ��  B   !   ��  ��     B   ��  ��  ��  !   C       ��  ��  C   !   ��     �   c   ��  ��  ��  A   "   ��  ��    ��A  ��  ��        ��          ! ��!       ��  ��  ��  ��      !   B   B       ��      ��  ��               ! ��B   ����B  !  ��         B  ������  ��  B   B   ������  ��  !   ��  :�  ��  C   B   ������     C   C     ��          |�  |�         B   B ��B ��c       ��       ���� ����!   B           ��  ����  ��   ��      ��  ��     !   C           B   c   !   ��  ��     B   ��      !  ��      ��  ��  ��
```

The wav files arrive in s3 the same size as when they left Twilio but when downloaded are unplayable or static.
This makes me think that it's a simple encoding issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: That is a text representation of your binary. When you say you expect binary, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Although the code below works I'd rather not use it, I'd rather copy the file directly to memory rather than buffering it to disk.

```
// read relevant file to disk
function bufferFile(file_name, file_location) {
    console.log(file_location);
    var tempstream = request(file_location).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_name));
        tempstream.on('finish', function (){
        file_contents = fs.createReadStream(file_name);
        awsS3 (file_name, file_contents);
        })
}
```